# Sitecore WFFM contact id is empty

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

for one of our customers, we use the wffm CombinedDataProver (SQL + Mongo).
When a form is posted from the content management server, this works perfectly.

However, when posting from a content delivery server, the contactid & interactionid fields are empty in SQL server.

[image: formdata table]

Anybody an idea what could be causing this?